# How to set the project type to Flutter in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'm having a problem understanding how to configure a Flutter project in Android Studio. I've done all the Flutter/Dart install steps and I can successfully build Flutter projects. My problem is setting the project so the Project View window in Android Studio sees my projects as Flutter projects and not an Android project. For example, here's a screenshot of a Flutter project I created:

[Android Studio Project View Java folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyRxX.png)

Notice the Java "coffee cup" on the flutter_app folder and the "[flutter_app_android]" on the android folder. Here's an example of a Flutter project that seems to correctly be identified as a Flutter project in Android Studio:

[Android Studio Project View Flutter folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbnr8.png)

I've tried creating new Flutter projects in Android Studio and by the flutter create  command line. This is driving me nuts and is probably something trivial but I can't find the setting that makes my project recognized as a Flutter project.

Comment: I know this is not an answer, but I'm using Visual Studio Code and it's been great. You can also see that the first Flutter screenshot on the main website shows a VSCode window. That must mean something. :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I typically use the project view as you have shown in your first image.  The Flutter code is in the lib folder.  Being able to see the 'android' and 'ios' folders can be helpful if you need to configure something specific like Firebase Cloud Messaging or you need to add channels to your Flutter app to call native iOS or Android code.